# Taine reference in Heidegger's 'What is metaphysics?'

Tags: reference-request, heidegger

In his inaugural speech 'What is Metaphysics?', in the first section[1], Heidegger characterizes science as being about 'being itself - and nothing more' ('das Seiende selbst - und weiter nichts'). In a footnote he claims this characterization is by French positivist Hippolyte Taine, but he does not give a reference. Where does Taine say anything like this?

[1] English: http://wagner.edu/psychology/files/2013/01/Heidegger-What-Is-Metaphysics-Translation-GROTH.pdf p.34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer:

> Le passage de Taine auquel Heidegger fait allusion se trouve dans la
>   *Philosophie de l'art*, 13e édition, Paris. Hachette. 1909, p. 12. Le
>   voici : « Mon seul devoir est de vous exposer des faits et de vous
>   montrer comment ces faits se sont produits. La méthode moderne que je
>   tache de suivre, et qui commence à s'introduire dans toutes les
>   sciences morales, consiste à considérer les œuvres humaines, et en
>   particulier les oeuvres d'art, comme des faits et des produits dont il
>   faut marquer les caractères et chercher les causes; rien de plus.
>   Ainsi comprise la science ne proscrit ni ne pardonne: elle constate et
>   explique ». - Dans une lettre à sa femme Elfride du 11 août 1936,
>   Heidegger lui demande de chercher l'ouvrage dans la bibliothèque de la
>   maison de Fribourg et de l'envoyer à la Halle (M. Heidegger, « Mein
>   liebes Seelchen! ». Briefe Martin Heideggers an seine Frau Elfride,
>   1915 - 1970, hg. von Gertrud Heidegger, Munich, Deutsche
>   Verlags-Anstalt, 2005. p. 192). Je remercie Jean-François Courtine
>   pour m'avoir signalé le passage de Taine.

Source:
Franco Volpi, *La grammaire et l'étymologie du mot être* in: J-Fr. Courtine (ed.), *L'introduction á la metaphysique de Heidegger* (Vrin), p.136
[google books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=o4MtajZUMsUC&pg=PA136)

So, it refers to Taine, *Philosophie de l'art*, p. 12 [google books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=WHhKOs6y4MEC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12):

> Mon seul devoir est de vous exposer des faits et de vous
>   montrer comment ces faits se sont produits. La méthode moderne que je
>   tache de suivre, et qui commence à s'introduire dans toutes les
>   sciences morales, consiste à considérer les œuvres humaines, et en
>   particulier les oeuvres d'art, comme des faits et des produits dont il
>   faut marquer les caractères et chercher les causes; rien de plus.
>   Ainsi comprise la science ne proscrit ni ne pardonne: elle constate et
>   explique.

The phrase he uses for 'and nothing more' is 'rien de plus'.

Comment: Yes "rien de plus' certainly means 'and nothing more.'  Heidegger is being more innovative though if he sees 'being itself/das Seiende selbst' in Taine here.